# Publishing ASP.NET 4.5 project guidance?

Tags: asp.net, web, hosting

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET project built using Visual Studio 2012 in .NET 4.5 on IIS 7.5

I have tried various tutorials on the web but cannot seem to figure out how to make it work.

What steps do I need to take to make sure everything works.

Error:
[image]

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: I would like to host this website on my laptop and share it with others via the domain - IIS keeps giving me this error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Comment: Ok. Now your tell what is your problem. I sugest you to update your main post. What version of IIS you are using on your laptop? Your application us located under C:\Inetpub\wwwroot  ?

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 - this folder is not located under C:\Inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: you setup virtual directory and assigned correct .NET version to it?

Comment: don't know how to do that - although some tutorials did mention that